# Sum of exponential distribution with parameter 1 and chi-square distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

As the title suggests, why is sum of n exponential distribution with parameter 1 following chi-square distribution with degree of freedom 2n?

Comment: 1. Presumably you intend to calculate the distribution of a sum of random variables, rather than to sum their distribution functions as in your title (which would not then be a distribution function). 2. You need to specify how the variables are related; presumably these are intended to be independent? 3. In what sense do you mean "why"? What sort of answer are you looking for? A proof? Is this an exercise for a class?

Comment: Actually you need rate parameter $\frac12$, i.e. scale parameter $2$, for your exponential distributions.  You also need them to be independent

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Show that a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom has the same probability density function as an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\frac12$
- Show that a random variable with a chi-square distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom has the same distribution as the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables with a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom
- (Not strictly necessary) Show that a random variable with a Gamma or Erlang distribution with shape parameter $n$ and rate parameter $\frac12$ has the same distribution as the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables with an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\frac12$